# J query : image pop up should appear while checking a custom field in Jira create issue screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira

I am searching for a Jquery function which should take the URL of a image and a pop up image should appear while checking a specific options of a radio button in create issue screen of Jira.

```
(function($) {
$('#customfield_12802-1').change(function() {
      alert('Image pop should come, instead of the alert box');

});
$('#customfield_12802-2').change(function() {
  alert('Image pop should come, instead of the alert box');
});
})(AJS.$);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a simple one-liner jQuery solution for that, but you can do it using a plugin, [`Dialog | jQuery UI`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for example:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rqnJM/)

**HTML:**

```
 <select id = "myList">
     <option value = "1">one</option>
     <option value = "2">two</option>
     <option value = "3">three</option>
     <option value = "4">four</option>
</select>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {    
    $('#dialog').html('<img src="/url/to/myImage.png" />')
        .dialog()
        .parent()
        .hide();
  });

$('#myList').change(function() {
      $( "#dialog").dialog().parent().show();
});
```